# ASP.NET MVC application users linq to join to other tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I am using default ASP.NET MVC 5 users identity to store and manage users in my database.

I have other database tables that will be referencing the users table.

The problem I am facing is how to extract user details when querying a certain table that has a foreign key (`userid`).

From what I have seen online, I cannot directly query the users table ("not best practice").

So I must use the `ApplicationDbContext` to get the list of users:

```
var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
var db_users = userContext.Users.Select(x => new UserSearchResult() 
{
  ApplicationUserId = x.Id,
  Email = x.Email,
  Username = x.UserName,
  Fullname = x.FullName
});
```

Then my linq query would be for example:

```
var query = (from dep in Dbcontext.Departments
             from usr in db_users.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == dep.HodUserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             join cat in Dbcontext.Categories on dep.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
             select new DepartmentSearchResult() 
             {
               DepartmentId = dep.DepartmentId,
               DepartmentName = dep.DepartmentName,
               HodName = usr.Fullname,
               CategoryName = cat.CategoryName
             });
```

However, the above will not work as SQL does not know about the `db_users`.

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: There is no problem referencing `users` table directly in query if you have a FK reference of its primary with `HodUserId`.

Comment: @sajal, the users table is not part of my dbcontext. So is it as simple as adding a dbset in dbcontext. Or is there other code that i need to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a navigation property of the User in the model you are using UserId as the foreign key. When querying that particular item include the user details.

say in your Department model

```
public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; } //Navigation Property
        public string UserId { get; set; }  //Foreign Key
    }
```

When you are querying Departments information in any action

```
var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var department = _context.Departments.Include(c => c.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here I used `FirstOrDefault()` to get a single(first to be exact) item from db. You can use any appropriate method as per your requirement.

Now in department, you can access User information by simply going through `department.User.FullName` or whatever property of the user you need

Comment: `var context = new ApplicationDbContext();` My departments are not part of an isntance of applicationDbContext.

Comment: I faced problems trying to figure out how to get this to work only to realise, that your solution is using one dbcontext (`applicationcontext`) where as my application is using `dbcontext` and `applicationcontext`. Once i got rid of the `dbcontext` and moved all my `dbsets` to `applicationcontext` your solution worked

Comment: You didn't mentioned it in the question and I also didn't noticed you were using two dbcontexts. Sorry about that. I am wondering why would you need several dbcontexts in your application?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this - You can either materialize the users you are interested in to a collection and join to this (but then the join will be done in memory), or you can put both tables in a single data context and do the join as normal. You shouldn't join across data contexts as they may both have inconsistent views of the database at the time of query...

Comment: thank you for that info. Is it a good, idea to keep another user table in the dbcontext, which will contain info like fullname, etc. and then query that table instead